# Adicionar saída do bash para texto

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Bem, estou tentando criar um log em texto, com os dias e horários em que foi executado meu script. Só que, por exemplo: quando uso **echo 10/03 - 13:20 >> log.txt** ele sobrepõe lá no arquivo de texto por ordem numérica, então está ficando mais ou menos assim o log:

```
09/01 - 10:43
10/03 - 13:20
12/03 - 12:05
```

Pensei em improvisar e colocar 1 -, 2 -, 3 - antes de cada data, mas acho que fica muita improvisação. Tem alguma forma de ordenar sem ser por forma numérica?

Comment: sua pergunta é confusa...você quer ordenar números mas não pode ser por ordem numérica ? pra mim não faz muito sentido

Comment: Colocando o comando de saída `>>` você está pedindo para colocar o conteúdo no final do arquivo, ou seja na ultima linha do arquivo de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o utilitário [date](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/date1.html) para recuperar a hora do sistema e formatá-la conforme sua necessidade, por exemplo:

```
$ date +"%F %T"
```

Saída:

```
2019-04-22 14:20:18
```

Para gravar a saída do utilitário em um arquivo texto sem sobreescrevê-lo, apenas concatenando o *timestamp* retornado no final do arquivo basta:

```
$ date +"%F %T" >> log.txt
```

Você pode escrever uma função capaz de registrar os eventos de log para facilitar sua a sua vida, por exemplo:

```
function log {
    DATE=$(date +"%F %T")
    echo "[${DATE}] - ${1}" >> log.txt
}
```

Exemplificando:

```
#!/bin/bash

function log {
    DATE=$(date +"%F %T")
    echo "[${DATE}] - ${1}" >> log.txt
}

# Regista timestamp antes do processamento
log "Inicio..."

# Faz alguma coisa
sleep 1

# Registra processamento
log "Processando..."

# Faz outra coisa
sleep 1

# Regista timestamp apos o processamento
log "Terminei!"
```

Arquivo de log gravado:

```
[2019-04-22 14:31:16] - Inicio...
[2019-04-22 14:31:17] - Processando...
[2019-04-22 14:31:18] - Terminei!
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!